# How can I calculate the growth rate from a column? R

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I got this data

```
library(WDI)
library(tidyverse)

wdi <- WDI(indicator = c("TG.VAL.TOTL.GD.ZS"),
           start=1961, end=2020)
wdi<-wdi %>% rename( `Comercio % PIB`=TG.VAL.TOTL.GD.ZS)
wdi<- wdi %>% filter(country=="Ecuador")
wdi<-wdi %>% select(-iso2c)
```

It seems something like this (image)

- I want the first to be 1961, not 2020.
- I want to calculate this formula in another column. I think it's with `mutate` command but I don't know how to do it.

formula (in latex):

growth rate = `\frac{year_{t}-year_{t-1}}{year_{t}}`

How can I do it?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be achieved via `dplyr::arrange` and `dplyr::lag` like so:

```r
library(WDI)
library(tidyverse)

wdi <- WDI(indicator = c("TG.VAL.TOTL.GD.ZS"),
           start=1961, end=2020)
wdi<-wdi %>% rename( `Comercio % PIB`=TG.VAL.TOTL.GD.ZS)
wdi<- wdi %>% filter(country=="Ecuador")
wdi <- wdi %>% 
  select(-iso2c) %>% 
  arrange(year) %>% 
  mutate(growth_rate = (`Comercio % PIB` - lag(`Comercio % PIB`)) / `Comercio % PIB`)

head(wdi)
#>   country Comercio % PIB year growth_rate
#> 1 Ecuador       13.28506 1961          NA
#> 2 Ecuador       15.87398 1962  0.16309210
#> 3 Ecuador       13.59392 1963 -0.16772579
#> 4 Ecuador       13.14531 1964 -0.03412751
#> 5 Ecuador       13.78271 1965  0.04624673
#> 6 Ecuador       13.54294 1966 -0.01770440
```